# Convert a vector of lists with uneven length to a matrix

Tags: r, list, matrix, coercion

I have a vector, well a data frame with only one column, that contains lists of uneven lengths:

```
data = list(
c(349, 364, 393, 356, 357, 394, 334, 394, 343, 365, 349),
c(390, 336, 752, 377),
c(670, 757, 405, 343, 1109, 350, 372),
c(0, 0),
c(),
c(1115, 394, 327, 356, 408, 329, 385, 357, 357))
```

and I would like to convert it to a matrix, filling the gaps with `NA`.
So it should look something like this:

```
349, 364, 393, 356, 357, 394, 334, 394, 343, 365, 349
390, 336, 752, 377, NA,  NA,  NA,  NA,  NA,  NA,  NA
670, 757, 405, 343, 1109,350, 372, NA,  NA,  NA,  NA
0,   0,   NA,  NA,  NA,  NA,  NA,  NA,  NA,  NA,  NA
NA,  NA,  NA,  NA,  NA,  NA,  NA,  NA,  NA,  NA,  NA                     
1115,394, 327, 356, 408, 329, 385, 357, 357, NA,  NA
```

eventually, even to get rid of the rows with only `NAs`. I have tried

```
data = sapply(data[,1], FUN=unlist)
```

and then

```
data = sapply(data, '[', seq(max(sapply(data, length))))
```

but I keep getting a matrix with all the elements unlisted in one column. Please advise.

Comment: Your `data` is giving errors.  Please check for typo.  Did you meant `list` instead of `as.vector`

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Corrected now. It is in fact a data frame with one column resulting from the `aggregate` function

Comment: Probably, you used the `list` as `FUN` in `aggregate` to `list` the `unique` elements.

Comment: No, I actually used `FUN=diff` in `aggregate` in order to get time differences between consecutive rows having the same identifier

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R: convert asymmetric list to matrix - number of elements in each sub-list differ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11148429/r-convert-asymmetric-list-to-matrix-number-of-elements-in-each-sub-list-diffe)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess the 'data' should be a `list` instead of a `vector`, then the code would work

```
t(sapply(data, `length<-`, max(lengths(data))))
```

NOTE: `lengths` is a faster option (introduced in the recent R versions) that replaces `sapply(data, length)`

#### data

```
data = list(
  c(349, 364, 393, 356, 357, 394, 334, 394, 343, 365, 349),
  c(390, 336, 752, 377),
  c(670, 757, 405, 343, 1109, 350, 372),
  c(0, 0),
  numeric(0),
  c(1115, 394, 327, 356, 408, 329, 385, 357, 357))
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. In my case, being a resulting `data.frame` with only one column, coming from the `aggregate` function, I had to do `t(sapply(data[,1], \`length<-\`, max(lengths(data[,1]))))` Of course it can always be coerced. Thanks once again!