# Filtering (grep) and trimming a list within a data.frame to create new variables

Tags: r, lapply

I have a data.frame (`tar`) with a variable (`clean.text`) that contains a list of munged text for every row.

For example:

```
[[2]]
 [1] "Dove go fresh Cucumber and Green Tea Beauty Bar combines the refreshing scent of cucumber and green tea with Dove's gentle cleansers and _ moisturizing cream. Dove Beauty Bar is proven to be more gentle and mild on skin than ordinary soap. It can be used on your hands and as a mild facial cleanser, so if you're also after a fresh face and refreshed hands throughout the day, why not try adding Dove Beauty Bar go fresh Cucumber and Green Tea to your skin care routine? Light, hydrating feel and refreshing formula that effectively nourishes skin. A refreshing shower can be just what you need to start the day off right. Dove's go fresh range blends nourishing ingredients and light, fresh scents in a formula that's gentle on your skin. Dove go fresh beauty bars give you a feeling of hydrating freshness that leaves you and your skin feeling blissfully revived. For best results: Your hands are one of the driest parts of your body so give them a boost and lather your Dove beauty bar between wet hands. Once you've covered your body with the rich lather, making sure to avoid contact with your eyes, rinse away thoroughly. At Dove, our vision is of a world where beauty is a source of confidence, and not anxiety. So, we are on a mission to help the next generation of women develop a positive relationship with the way they look - helping them raise their self-esteem and realize their full potential."
 [2] "Scent: Cucumber"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
 [3] "Health Facts: Sulfate-free"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
 [4] "Suggested Age: 5 Years and Up"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
 [5] "Wellness Standard: Aluminum-free, paraben-free"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
 [6] "Recommended Skin Type: Normal"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
 [7] "Beauty Purpose: Moisturizing, basic cleansing"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
 [8] "Package Quantity: 1"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
 [9] "TCIN: 10819409"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
[10] "UPC: 011111611023"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
[11] "Item Number (DPCI): 049-00-0604"
```

I have built a simple `grepl` function that trims the list to the relevant row when matching to a string, and then (very hackily) writes those values into a variable. For example, I might filter for the string "Health Facts:" and write relevant data into a variable called `health_facts`.

Example:

```
tar$health_facts = lapply(tar$clean.text, function(l) l[grepl(tar[[top_attribute_names]], l)])
tar$health_facts<-gsub(".*: ","",as.character(tar$health_facts))
tar$health_facts<-ifelse(tar$health_facts=='character(0)',NA,tar$health_facts)  # Lists that don't contain health facts will say character(0)
```

With the hope of building a function rather than copy-and-pasting the same code, I then put together two lists of variables: the strings that I want to `grep` for, and the names of the corresponding variables I'd like to create.

```
`top_attribute_names<-c("Item_Number (DPCI)","UPC","TCIN","Product Form","Package Quantity",
"Health Facts")`

> new_attribute_names<-c("DCPI","UPC","TCIN","product_form","package_quantity","health_facts")
```

I am trying to write a simply loop that filters the text field for the desired values and writes them to new variables:

```
for (i in seq_along(top_attribute_names)) {
      new_list<-lapply(tar$clean.text, function(l) l[grepl(top_attribute_names[i], l)]) # Write items that match into new list
     tar[new_attribute_names[i]]<-new_list[1] # Only take first row, just in case there is a text duplicate
    }
```

***UPDATED***:  The `grepl` is not working the same way when I reference items in the list versus pasting the text in the same function. I'm just looking for help to make the last bit work, but certainly open to other improvements.

**Sample data:**

```
>dput(tar$clean.text[1:10])
list(c("Dove go fresh Cucumber and Green Tea Beauty Bar combines the refreshing scent of cucumber and green tea with Dove's gentle cleansers and _ moisturizing cream. Dove Beauty Bar is proven to be more gentle and mild on skin than ordinary soap. It can be used on your hands and as a mild facial cleanser, so if you're also after a fresh face and refreshed hands throughout the day, why not try adding Dove Beauty Bar go fresh Cucumber and Green Tea to your skin care routine? Light, hydrating feel and refreshing formula that effectively nourishes skin. A refreshing shower can be just what you need to start the day off right. Dove's go fresh range blends nourishing ingredients and light, fresh scents in a formula that's gentle on your skin. Dove go fresh beauty bars give you a feeling of hydrating freshness that leaves you and your skin feeling blissfully revived. For best results: Your hands are one of the driest parts of your body so give them a boost and lather your Dove beauty bar between wet hands. Once you've covered your body with the rich lather, making sure to avoid contact with your eyes, rinse away thoroughly. At Dove, our vision is of a world where beauty is a source of confidence, and not anxiety. So, we are on a mission to help the next generation of women develop a positive relationship with the way they look - helping them raise their self-esteem and realize their full potential.", 
    "Scent: Cucumber", "Health Facts: Sulfate-free", "Suggested Age: 5 Years and Up", 
    "Wellness Standard: Aluminum-free, paraben-free", "Recommended Skin Type: Normal", 
    "Beauty Purpose: Moisturizing, basic cleansing", "Package Quantity: 1", 
    "TCIN: 10819409", "UPC: 011111611023", "Item Number (DPCI): 049-00-0604"
    ), c("Me! Bath Bath Bomb Papaya Nectar 6 ct is a great idea to add to a spa gift basket. These bath bombs are like scoops for your bath to make mini bath ice cream that gives you super soft skin.", 
    "Scent: Fruit", "Health Facts: Vegan, paraben-free, aluminum-free", 
    "Product Form: Bath bomb", "Suggested Age: Adult Use Only", "Wellness Standard: Aluminum-free, cruelty-free, paraben-free, vegan", 
    "Recommended Skin Type: Normal", "Sustainability Claims: Cruelty-free", 
    "TCIN: 18828570", "UPC: 858858000358", "Item Number (DPCI): 037-08-1164"
    ), NA_character_, NA_character_, c("Aura Cacia pure essential oils in 4 fl oz Body Oil has a lavender and cocoa butter scent. This natural skin care oil shows skin tone improvement that you can feel.", 
    "Scent: Lavender, Cocoa Butter", "Health Facts: Contains lavender, butylparaben-free, phthalate-free, formaldehyde donor-free, formaldehyde-free, nonylphenol ethoxylate free, propylparaben-free, Sulfate-free, paraben-free, dye-free, aluminum-free", 
    "Product Form: Lotion", "Suggested Age: All Ages", "Recommended Skin Type: Normal", 
    "Beauty Purpose: Skin tone improvement", "Sustainability Claims: Not tested on animals, cruelty-free", 
    "TCIN: 50030689", "UPC: 051381911720", "Item Number (DPCI): 037-05-1378"
    ), c("Deep clean pores with the Facial Cleansing Brush from Eco", 
    "Tools. This compact brush features soft bristles for moderate exfoliation, leaving you with soft, supple skin. Your serums and moisturizers can more effectively penetrate your skin once all the dead skin cells are out of the way. The compact size is ideal for packing in your weekend tote or suitcase for cleansing on the go.", 
    "Material: Nylon", "Suggested Age: All Ages", "Beauty Purpose: Basic cleansing, exfoliating", 
    "TCIN: 52537254", "UPC: 079625074864", "Item Number (DPCI): 037-08-2254"
    ), c("Deep Steep Rosemary Mint Sugar Scrub gently exfoliates dead skin cells while moisturizing, leaving smooth, radiant, polished skin. This formula is made up of a smooth blend of shea butter, cocoa butter and carefully sourced sugar to give you light, blissful fragrance with just the right amount of exfoliation and no harsh scratching. Apply desired amount of Deep Steep Rosemary Mint Sugar Scrub to wet skin from shoulders to ankles. Massage in a circular motion. Rinse.", 
    "Scent: Rosemary", "Health Facts: Contains argan oil, contains coconut oil, contains shea butter, formaldehyde donor-free, gluten-free, dye-free, ethyl alcohol-free, paraben-free, phthalate-free, vegan", 
    "Product Form: Scrub", "Suggested Age: All Ages", "Recommended Skin Type: Dry, normal", 
    "Beauty Purpose: Exfoliating", "TCIN: 53242409", "UPC: 674749101153", 
    "Item Number (DPCI): 037-08-2123"), NA_character_, c("Want to feel gorgeously soft skin every day? Transform your daily shower into an irresistible treat with the exquisitely fragranced Caress Evenly Gorgeous body wash. Indulge your skin with a rich exfoliating lather delicately scented with burnt brown sugar and karite butter that makes this body wash smell good enough to eat. Subtle notes of soft crisp apple and berry open up to a bold floral heart, while rich scents of warm tonka bean, vanilla and balsam together round out the lush lather to leave you with perfectly buffed and glowing skin. Caress Evenly Gorgeous is a revitalizing body wash that blends rich, luxurious lather with expertly crafted fine fragrance It is a body wash that gently cleanses your skin to leave it delicately fragrant, beautifully soft.", 
    "Lather up and indulge in a deeply cleansing and reviving shower experience. With fine floral fragrance and gentle exfoliates, Caress Evenly Gorgeous will leave you feeling delicately perfumed and silky-smooth, making this the perfect body wash for every day? and every night. Caress body wash and beauty bar fragrances are crafted by the world's best perfumers to transform your daily shower into an indulging experience that will make you feel special every day?Scent: Fresh", 
    "Health Facts: Aluminum-free, paraben-free, fluoride-free", "Product Form: Liquid", 
    "Suggested Age: 5 Years and Up", "Wellness Standard: Aluminum-free, paraben-free", 
    "Recommended Skin Type: Normal", "Beauty Purpose: Basic cleansing", 
    "Package Quantity: 1", "TCIN: 13446229", "UPC: 011111014909", 
    "Item Number (DPCI): 049-00-0806"), c("Maintain a sanitary and healthy atmosphere with the MEDLINE n/a READYBATH, PREMIUM,FRAG FREE, 8/PK - 24pks. These sterile swab sticks are pre-treated with povidone-iodine for preparing skin for incision and other medical issues. Comes in disposable packages of 3.", 
    "Scent: Unscented", "Health Facts: No fragrance added", "Suggested Age: Adult Use Only", 
    "Recommended Skin Type: Normal", "Beauty Purpose: Basic cleansing", 
    "Package Quantity: 1", "TCIN: 14339945", "UPC: 080196731445", 
    "Item Number (DPCI): 037-13-0198"))`
```

Comment: Quick guess is the problem is `for (i in top_attribute_names)`. In R this passes the actual values of `top_attribute_names`. Try `for (i in seq_along(top_attribute_names))`

Comment: That got it working, but it threw an error because some rows are finding more than one match (v dirty data): `replacement element 3027 has 2 rows, need 17359`. Any thoughts on how to force it to take the top row during the function?

Comment: Update: that's not the issue. The `grepl` is not working the same when I reference the list that contains the text, resulting in blank values. Updating my Q below.

Comment: I think there are a few problems here - one is that some of values of `top_attribute_names` don't match anything in `tar$clean.text`. Another is that grepl will necessarily return a list and if I understand your question correctly you really only want it to return a single value. Is that right?

Comment: To clarify, "Item_Number_(DPCI)" doesn't appear in the text anywhere. And if you remove the underscores your grep will treat the parentheses as a capture group. You could change that value to `"Item Number \\(DPCI\\)"`

Comment: Great catch on the DPCI parentheses - thank you. top_attribute_names are generated by calculating frequency of occurrence in the real dataset, so I've just done a bad job in selecting my example data. Re: selecting a single value from the list, I added some simple logic to my function that select the first row from the list -- technically the dataset should only have each attribute name once, but it's very messy so this is a good safeguard (see `new_rows`). The loop runs now I've made those changes, so I think it's `function(l) l[grepl(top_attribute_names[i], l)])` that still needs repair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so after addressing the issues above, I think this should solve the problem:

```
top_attribute_names<-c("Item Number \\(DPCI\\)",
                       "UPC",
                       "TCIN", 
                       "Product Form",
                       "Package_Quantity",
                       "Health_Facts")
new_attribute_names<-c("DCPI",
                       "UPC",
                       "TCIN",
                       "product_form",
                       "package_quantity",
                       "health_facts")

my_grep_function <- function(x){
    val <- grepl(top_attribute_names[i], x)
    val_out <- ifelse(sum(val) > 0, x[val], NA)
    return(val_out)
}

for (i in seq_along(top_attribute_names)) {
    tar[new_attribute_names[i]] <- rapply(tar$clean.text, my_grep_function)
}
```

So first in the `top_attribute_names` you want to make sure that all of these things are valid regex. This is why you need to double escape the parentheses.

The function that you ultimately want to call in the `apply` could be condensed to a single line but it would be really ugly so I've defined it separately. It appears that not every entry in your data.frame has every field you're searching for

Then in the crucial bit, you want to use `rapply` because you want to apply this function recursively to a list of lists.

As an alternative, you could transform your list of lists into a data.frame of its own (following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11148603/4325492) very helpful answer):

```
max_len <- max(sapply(tar$clean.text, length))
corrected_text <- lapply(tar$clean.text, function(x) {c(x, rep(NA, max.len - length(x)))})
new_data_frame <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, corrected_text), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

You need the first two lines because not every list in `tar$clean.text` is the same length. And I assume these would be the next steps:

```
names(new_data_frame) <- c("Slogan", sub(":.*", "", new_data_frame[1,2:12]))
names(new_data_frame) <- gsub(" ", "_", names(new_data_frame))

for(i in 3:11){
    new_data_frame[[i]] <- sub("^.*?:\\s+", "", new_data_frame[[i]])
}
```

The downside to the second strategy is that because you have these unequal lists and you pad everything with NAs at the end, you are going to introduce some error. In the sample you provide, for example, the 9th entry has its DPCI pushed into the final column, which is NA for all other values. The plus side is that you get that first bit into a useable form. But that could also be accomplished another way:

```
get_first_function <- function(x){
    return(x[[1]])
}
tar$slogan <- rapply(tar$clean.text, get_first_function)
```

Of run the `do.call` method above and then `tar$slogan_2 <- new_data_frame[[1]]`

Comment: Thank you! Function above works if you replace `new_attribute_names` in the `grepl` to `top_attribute_names`.

Comment: Oops - I was getting a little tired there. It's edited now for future reference and glad I could help!